# How to print object name in CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs

```js
var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
console.log(stage.constructor.name);//prints a
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
 <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="500" height="300">
        alternate content
 </canvas>
```

I am trying to print the constructor name in create js but it is printing `a`.Is there any solution to print constructor name.

Comment: Then probably the constructor name is "a" :), which makes sense since the code is minified

Comment: @codtex you can check there consturctor is  `new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas")`.

Comment: If it is minified is there any to get that constructor name.

Comment: I don't think so. `object.constructor` is simply a function and `name` property returns the name of this function

Comment: What exactly do you need and why?

Comment: `@codtex `I am having some object in my create js files  like the following objects.                                        `this.wss = new lib.Westernsatraps_100AD()`; I need to show their names to the user.

Comment: Hi @VAMSEE MOHAN KRISHNA , yes, Khauri McClain is correct you are seeing an "a" because you are using the min version of the CJS libs. This is a compressed version of the libs meaning class names can are condensed to make the file as small as possible. However if you want to see the type coming back I would recommend you use the non-minified version https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.combined.js Here you'll "Stage" and not an "a". Secondly you should be getting a type "lib.Westernsatraps_100AD {_listeners: null,..." you should be a able to assign an .name to display to your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateJS is minified. That means that a lot of the variable names of things not directly accessible have been shortened in order to make the code smaller. Check out this simplified example.

```js
let a = function(){}

let Closure = {
  MyClass : a
}

let myInstance = new Closure.MyClass(); 

console.log(myInstance.constructor.name) // a
```

If you were to only look at the last two lines you would expect that the constructor of `Closure.MyClass` would be MyClass, but as you can see the constructor is actually `a` since that's the `name` of the `constructor` function that `Closure.MyClass` mentions.

Maybe you should rethink the way you're using/creating the objects. If you have the ability to, then attach the name yourself either in the constructor of the object or after the object is created and reference that name.

```js
let a = function(){ this.name = "MyClass" }

let Closure = {
  MyClass : a
}

let myInstance = new Closure.MyClass(); 

myInstance.name2 = "MyClass"; // alternative method

console.log(myInstance.name) // MyClass
console.log(myInstance.name2) // MyClass
```

There's also other ways you might be able to accomplish what you want, you might have to get creative. Or you could try using the un-minified version of the library.